# Unable to extract array/list from dataframe, AnalysisException : need struct type but got binary

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Dataset with String[], and I am struggling to extract columns out of it. Here's the code

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

//Read parquet data
Dataset<Row> readerDF = spark.readStream().format("parquet").

List<String> columns = Arrays.asList("city","country");
//Interested in only field in data for now 'fieldMap' which is Map<String,String>

Dataset<String[]> stringArrDF = readerDF.map((MapFunction<Row, String[]>) row -> {                
    Map<String,String> fields = row.getJavaMap(row.fieldIndex("fieldMap"));
    List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<>();                
    columns.forEach(columnName ->
    {
        columnList.add(fields.getOrDefault(columnName, ""));
    });
    return columnList.toArray(new String[columns.size]);
}, Encoders.kryo(String[].class));

//I was expecting to extract city here:
Dataset ds = stringArrDF.select(col("value").getItem(1).as("city"));
```

But it fails with below exception.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Can't extract value from value#22;

How can I access a String[] or List field from a Dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting below error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Can't extract value from value#22: need struct type but got binary;

You are using `Encoders.kryo(String[].class)` for creating `stringArrDF`. If you check the documentation for `Encoders.kryo`, it says

> Creates an encoder that serializes objects of type T using Kryo. This
>   encoder maps T into a single byte array (binary) field.

Use `spark.implicits().newStringArrayEncoder()` for encoding your String[].

Comment: How can I go about making it work with Kryo? Or is it just for custom datatypes? Any good tutorial along these lines?

Comment: You can refer to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets and https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-Encoder.html